# Migrating ViewRenderer to MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to migrate one of our apps to MAUI from Xamarin Forms, but I am hitting some issues with one of our customer renderers.

We have a custom renderer which when clicking on an Entry it expands the margin so that the keyboard does not cover the Entry we are typing into.

I have moved the code into the sample MAUI one. Moving the classes to the respective folders (Controls, iOS Platform) and registered it via the ConfigureMauiHandlers functionality.
I followed the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers

However the elements are being drawn outside of the screen as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSYjo.png)

When changing the custom control to a grid it all renders correctly.
[Rendering correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n5rt.png)

Below is the code that I have put into the default MAUI project.

`KeyboardGrid.cs`

```cs
namespace TestLink
{
    public class KeyboardGrid : Grid
    {
    }
}
```

`KeyboardGridRenderer.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace TestLink
{
    public class KeyboardGridRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        private NSObject _keyboardShowObserver;
        private NSObject _keyboardHideObserver;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                RegisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }
        }

        private void RegisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver == null)
            {
                _keyboardShowObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow(OnKeyboardShow);
            }

            if (_keyboardHideObserver == null)
            {
                _keyboardHideObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide(OnKeyboardHide);
            }
        }

        private void OnKeyboardShow(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            NSValue result = (NSValue)args.Notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey));
            CGSize keyboardSize = result.RectangleFValue.Size;
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, keyboardSize.Height - 1); // push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
            }
        }

        private void OnKeyboardHide(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); // set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
            }
        }

        private void UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardShowObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardShowObserver = null;
            }

            if (_keyboardHideObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardHideObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardHideObserver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage.Xaml.cs`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:TestLink;assembly=TestLink"
             x:Class="TestLink.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <customControls:KeyboardGrid>
            <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="50"
            Padding="30,0">

                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Entry
                    x:Name="DoNotHideEntry"
                    Placeholder="Do not hide me"
                    Text=""
                    BackgroundColor="HotPink"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </customControls:KeyboardGrid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried to convert it to a handler but I am not sure what ViewRenderer would translate to in MAUI.

Comment: Take a look at Shane Neuville repo [FixesAndWorkarounds](https://github.com/PureWeen/ShanedlerSamples/tree/main). He has a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to convert it to a handler but I am not sure what ViewRenderer would translate to in MAUI.

`ViewRenderer` is similar to `ViewHandler` in [MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler). Like this:

```cs
public partial class KeyboardGridHandler : ViewHandler<KeyboardGrid, LayoutView>
{
   //the code that is similar to your KeyboardGridRenderer
```

For more details and steps you can refer to the official wiki: [Porting Custom Renderers to Handlers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers).